# What is wrong with my DropDown editor for a jqxGrid column?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I have this jqxGrid setup:

```
var paymentSource = {
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
        { name: 'Id', type: 'number' },
        { name: 'Name', type: 'string' }
    ],
    url: "@Url.Action("GetPaymentSchemes")"
};
var paymentAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(paymentSource, { autoBind: true });

var gridSource =
{
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
        { name: 'Name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'PaymentSchemeId', type: 'number' },
        { name: 'IsActive', type: 'boolean' },
        { name: 'Remarks', type: 'string' }
    ],
    url: "@Url.Action("GetParkades")"
};

var gridDataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(gridSource);
$("#index-grid").jqxGrid(
    {
        theme: theme,
        width: 900,
        source: gridDataAdapter,
        editable: true,
        columns: [
            { text: "Name", datafield: "Name", width: 300 },
            {
                text: 'Payment Scheme',
                datafield: 'PaymentSchemeId',
                displayfield: 'Name',
                columntype: 'dropdownlist',
                createeditor: function(row, value, editor) {
                    editor.jqxDropDownList({ source: paymentAdapter, displayMember: 'Name', valueMember: 'Id' });
                }
            },
            { text: "Active", datafield: "IsActive", width: 50, columntype: 'checkbox' },
            { text: "Operator Remarks", datafield: "Remarks" }
        ]
    });
```

The "Payment Scheme" column shows the same text value as the "Name" column when the page loads. When I double click "Payment Scheme", I get the correctly populated dropdown, but when I select a value, and leave the cell to end editing, the "Name" column now shows the same text as the "Payment Scheme" column. Do the two `Name` fields in different sources and adapters conflict? What is up here?

Comment: `url: "@Url.Action("GetPaymentSchemes")"` this cannot be right!

Comment: @Amberlamps It is right, and it works. You need to brush up on your Razor a bit, it seems. The inner @Url.Action(("GetPaymentSchemes") resolves to a proper url when the view compiles, resulting in `url: http://myapp/Parkade/GetPaymentSchemes`.

Comment: Alright, I did not know that it was precompiled!

Comment: It isn't recompiled. The fact is just that Razor expressions are resolved before other mark-up when the view is dynamically compiled.

Comment: I did not say recompiled, but **pre**compiled.

Comment: I made a typo. I meant it's not **pre**compiled.

Comment: Can you provide a demo link with the problem? Also, what version of jqx widgets do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line

```
//displayfield: 'Name',
```

Add cellvaluechanging event

```
cellvaluechanging: function (row, datafield, columntype, oldvalue, newvalue) {
    if (newvalue != oldvalue) {
        var item = paymentSource.localdata.find(function(element) {
            return element.Name == newvalue;
        });
        if (item) {
            return item.Id;
        }
    } else {
        return oldvalue;
    }
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/t0owapum/ (***You need to modify it to fit your case!***)

html code:

```
<div id="index-grid"></div>
```

JavaScript + jQuery code:

```
var paymentSource = {
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
        { name: 'Id', type: 'number' },
        { name: 'Name', type: 'string' }
    ],
    localdata: [
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Scheme 1' },
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Scheme 2' },
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Scheme 3' }
    ]
};
var paymentAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(paymentSource, { autoBind: true });

var gridSource = {
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
        { name: 'Name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'PaymentSchemeId', type: 'number' },
        { name: 'IsActive', type: 'boolean' },
        { name: 'Remarks', type: 'string' }
    ],
    localdata: [
        { Name: 'Parkade 1', PaymentSchemeId: 1, IsActive: true, Remarks: 'Remark 1' },
        { Name: 'Parkade 2', PaymentSchemeId: 2, IsActive: false, Remarks: 'Remark 2' },
        { Name: 'Parkade 3', PaymentSchemeId: 3, IsActive: true, Remarks: 'Remark 3' }
    ]
};
var gridDataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(gridSource);

$("#index-grid").jqxGrid({
    width: 900,
    source: gridDataAdapter,
    editable: true,
    columns: [
        { text: "Name", datafield: "Name", width: 300 },
        {
            text: 'Payment Scheme',
            datafield: 'PaymentSchemeId',
            //displayfield: 'Name',
            columntype: 'dropdownlist',
            createeditor: function(row, value, editor) {
                editor.jqxDropDownList({ source: paymentAdapter, displayMember: 'Name', valueMember: 'Id' });
            },
            cellvaluechanging: function (row, datafield, columntype, oldvalue, newvalue) {
                if (newvalue != oldvalue) {
                    var item = paymentSource.localdata.find(function(element) {
                        return element.Name == newvalue;
                    });
                    if (item) {
                        return item.Id;
                    }
                } else {
                    return oldvalue;
                }
            }
        },
        { text: "Active", datafield: "IsActive", width: 50, columntype: 'checkbox' },
        { text: "Operator Remarks", datafield: "Remarks" }
    ]
});
```